# C++ Mismatch function to call

Tags: c++, function

May I know what is wrong with the codes?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Vehicle
{
    double price = 0;
public:
    void setPrice(double p)
    {
        price = p;
    }
    double comparePrices(const Vehicle&, Vehicle&);
};

double Vehicle::comparePrices(const Vehicle& car1, Vehicle& car2)
{
    cout << "Enter the price for the used car: ";
    double price;
    cin >> price;
    car2.setPrice(price);
    return car1.price - car2.price;
}

int main()
{
    Vehicle newCar, usedCar;
    double diff;
    newCar.setPrice(38000);
    diff = newCar.comparePrices(newCar, usedCar);
    cout << "Used car price is $" << usedCar.setPrice();
    cout << ", the difference is $" << diff << endl;
}
```

After execution, I am getting this error

> error: no matching function for call to 'Vehicle::setPrice()'|

Comment: `setPrice` requires a value be provided. `void setPrice(**double p**)` Note that it also returns `void`. You cannot send `void` to `cout`. Do you mean to have a `getPrice` method?

Comment: *May I know what is wrong with the codes?* – It's unreadable because it isn't properly indented?

Comment: @Swordfish Better?

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, now it's better.

Comment: I wouldn't expect `Vehicle::comparePrices()` to ask for user input. It should be a free function. When it's a member i'd expect it to compare the price of a car provided as argument to the price of the car the function is called upon.

Answer (score 2):

I see a few things wrong:

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

Get out of the habit of using that. See [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/).

> ```
> double comparePrices(const Vehicle&, Vehicle&);
> ```

`comparePrices()` is a non-`static` method, which means you need to call it on a `Vehicle` object, as well as pass in two `Vehicle` objects as input parameters.  That is a bit wasteful and redundant.  Either make `comparePrices()` static, or else remove one of the `Vehicle` parameters and use the implicit `this` parameter to access the object being called on.

Also, just from a design perspective, `comparePrices()` should not be prompting the user for input.  That job belongs in `main()` before calling `comparePrices()`.

> ```
> cout << "Used car price is $" << usedCar.setPrice();
> ```

`setPrice()` takes a `double` as input, but you are not passing in a `double` value.  That is what the compiler error is complaining about.

Also, `setPrice()` does not have a return value, its return type is `void`, so you can't pass it to `operator<<`.  You need to add a separate `getPrice()` method to the `Vehicle` class to return its `price` member.

With that said, try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

class Vehicle
{
private:
    double price = 0;
public:
    double getPrice() const
    {
        return price;
    }

    void setPrice(double p)
    {
        price = p;
    }

    static double comparePrices(const Vehicle&, const Vehicle&);
};

double Vehicle::comparePrices(const Vehicle& v1, const Vehicle& v2)
{
    return v1.price - v2.price;
}

int main()
{
    Vehicle newCar, usedCar;
    double price, diff;

    newCar.setPrice(38000);

    std::cout << "Enter the price for the used car: ";
    std::cin >> price;
    usedCar.setPrice(price);

    diff = Vehicle::comparePrices(newCar, usedCar);
    std::cout << "Used car price is $" << usedCar.getPrice();
    std::cout << ", the difference is $" << diff << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Vehicle
{
private:
    double price = 0;
public:
    double getPrice() const
    {
        return price;
    }

    void setPrice(double p)
    {
        price = p;
    }

    double comparePrices(const Vehicle&);
};

double Vehicle::comparePrices(const Vehicle& other)
{
    return price - other.price;
}

int main()
{
    Vehicle newCar, usedCar;
    double price, diff;

    newCar.setPrice(38000);

    std::cout << "Enter the price for the used car: ";
    std::cin >> price;
    usedCar.setPrice(price);

    diff = newCar.comparePrices(usedCar);
    std::cout << "Used car price is $" << usedCar.getPrice();
    std::cout << ", the difference is $" << diff << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "Used car price is $" << usedCar.setPrice();
```

this line makes errors

return type of **setPrice()** is **void**

you should make things like **Vehicle::getPrice()** to get value of Price.

Comment: While that is a bug in the code, that's not the error being asked about.

Answer (score 0):

setPrice takes a double as a parameter but you called it without a parameter

```
cout << "Used car price is $" << usedCar.setPrice()
```

so the function signature doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

cout << "Used car price is $" << usedCar.setPrice();

Instead of this, just add an accessor method getPrice()
that just returns the price of the car. It should work then. setPrice() requires a parameter to be passed in but you aren't giving it anything when you cout it.